# Pandas : Produce alternative rows with melt on multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, alternate, pandas-melt

Say I have a dataframe

```
data_dict = {'Number': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'mw link': {0: 'SAM3703_2SAM3944 2', 1: 'SAM3720_2SAM4115 2', 2: 'SAM3729_2SAM4121_ 2'}, 'site_a': {0: 'SAM3703', 1: 'SAM3720', 2: 'SAM3729'}, 'name_a': {0: 'Chelak', 1: 'KattakurganATC', 2: 'Payariq'}, 'site_b': {0: 'SAM3944', 1: 'SAM4115', 2: 'SAM4121'}, 'name_b': {0: 'Turkibolo', 1: 'Kattagurgon Sement Zavod', 2: 'Payariq Dehgonobod'}, 'distance km': {0: 3.618, 1: 7.507, 2: 9.478}, 'manufacture': {0: 'ZTE NR 8150/8250', 1: 'ZTE NR 8150/8250', 2: 'ZTE NR 8150/8250'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

[image]

**Expected Output :**

There are these two columns `site_a` and `site_b` which I want to melt into rows but applying a simple melt gives output in series, I want them to be in an alternate fashion.

```
  Number    mw link         distance km  manufacture       variable value
0   1   SAM3703_2SAM3944 2    3.618     ZTE NR 8150/8250    site_a  SAM3703
1   1   SAM3703_2SAM3944 2    3.618     ZTE NR 8150/8250    site_b  SAM3944
2   2   SAM3720_2SAM4115 2    7.507     ZTE NR 8150/8250    site_a  SAM3720
3   2   SAM3720_2SAM4115 2    7.507     ZTE NR 8150/8250    site_b  SAM4115
4   3   SAM3729_2SAM4121_ 2   9.478     ZTE NR 8150/8250    site_a  SAM3729
5   3   SAM3729_2SAM4121_ 2   9.478     ZTE NR 8150/8250    site_b  SAM4121
```

**My Solution :**

This is what I have tried

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Number', 'mw link', 'distance km', 'manufacture'], value_vars=['site_a', 'site_b'])
```

which gives me :

[image]

Comment: and what is unwanted/incorrect?

Comment: check `which gives me :` it contains output in a serial manner for each column

Comment: Still can you be explicit? The format of your output is unclear. If just looks like you  need preprocessing of the columns.

Comment: @mozway updated my questiom, check expected and current ouput

Comment: A few descriptive sentences would be better IMO.

Comment: There are these two columns `site_a` and `site_b` which I want to melt into rows but applying a simple melt gives output in series, I want them to be in an alternate fashion.

Comment: So the order is an issue? Not the wrongly concatenated column?

Comment: wdym by wrongly concatenated, the output that I expect is in correct manner

Comment: the fact that you seemingly have separate 'distance' and 'km' columns in the expected output, but if this is order, this question is already answered

Comment: Thats formatting error, let me correct that

Comment: Yes, it's already answered, please read the duplicate. What is wrong with closing a duplicate?

Comment: Over here I have a number column, on which we sorted but what if there was no number column

Comment: then you add it with `groupby` on `mw_link`, or read the duplicate, there is a solution that doesn't require sorting

Comment: How is my question?

Comment: `there is a solution that doesn't require sorting` : that solution is deprecated `pivot_longer`

Answer (score 2):

You just add `sort_values(['Number', 'variable'])`:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Number', 'mw link', 'distance km', 'manufacture'], value_vars=['site_a', 'site_b']).sort_values(['Number', 'variable'])
```

[image]

Alternatives:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Number', 'mw link', 'distance km', 'manufacture'], value_vars=['site_a', 'site_b']).sort_values(['mw link', 'variable'])
```

Or:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Number', 'mw link', 'distance km', 'manufacture'], value_vars=['site_a', 'site_b']).sort_values(['distance km', 'variable'])
```

Comment: what if I don't have a Number column? I am saying this because this column was added manually to take care of other issue

Comment: Based on the provided data you can use `pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Number', 'mw link', 'distance km', 'manufacture'], value_vars=['site_a', 'site_b']).sort_values(['mw link', 'variable'])` or `pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Number', 'mw link', 'distance km', 'manufacture'], value_vars=['site_a', 'site_b']).sort_values(['distance km', 'variable'])` to get the same result. I added those to my answer.

Comment: okay, will wait for some more answers, ll accept it in a day